# ssh ignores variables in profile files

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables

Apologies for this vague question in advance, but I don't know how to narrow this down.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, using `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014` as my ssh client. I set up passwordless ssh according to these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html.

Now, ssh works as expected, *except* all variables that I define in `.bashrc` or `.profile` are ignored (yes, I'm aware that `.profile` sources `.bashrc`).  All posts related to this issue I could find on askubuntu.com, or stackexchange or the like did not solve this issue.

Local variables exist on both the local and the remote machine, but when I `ssh` into the remote machine, they aren't there, which means they're missing from the output of 'ssh ab.cd.efg.hij env'; likewise, `ssh ab.cd.efg.hij 'echo $LOCAL_VARIABLE'` gives no output.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

**EDIT**

I did not have `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` on the remote machine, as asked by steeldriver.  I added `export LOCAL_VARIABLE=foo` to one and then the other, but it's still missing from 'ssh ab.cd.efg.hij env' and `ssh ab.cd.efg.hij 'echo $LOCAL_VARIABLE'`.

Comment: Do you have a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` on the remote machine?

Comment: OK I read your question again and now I'm confused - are you expecting your local shell environment to be inherited by the remote shell when you start an SSH session?

Comment: Yes and no.  I'm trying to use openmpi via a proprietary software.  I need SSH to recognize `$LOCAL_VARIABLE` so openmpi works with the application I'm using (proprietary software).  Customer support and I have narrowed the issue down to `$LOCAL_VARIABLE` (which is the path to the license file for the program) not being available via SSH.  It doesn't matter to me if `$LOCAL_VARIABLE` is inherited by SSH, or if it is read (not sure "read" is the proper term) by SSH on the remote machine.  Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Not for me - sorry. Unless you are asking something like this: [When ssh'ing, how can I set an environment variable on the server that changes from session to session?](https://superuser.com/questions/163167/when-sshing-how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-server-that-changes-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash reads `.profile`* when run as an interactive login shell. When a command is given for execution, or when running a script, it is non-interactive unless you give the `-i` option, and non-login unless you give the `-l` option, etc. Neither of this is usually possible when executing commands via SSH.

Bash does read `.bashrc` when run non-interactively by SSH. However, the default `.bashrc` includes a check for interactive use:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

So effectively, no variable set in `.profile` or `.bashrc` is available when you do `ssh foo some-command`. You can put the variables in `.bashrc` before the check for interactive execution. For example:

```
$ head ~/.bashrc
echo foo
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
$ ssh localhost env
foo
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
SSH_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1 46916 127.0.0.1 22
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=155
USER=muru
...
```

The `echo foo` was executed. If I had `export foo=bar`, then `foo` would have showed up in the `env` output.

* with suitable caveats about the presence of files like `.bash_profile`, etc.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you very much. Just for others who run into the same problem: in my .bashrc, the check for interactive execution looks like this: `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`.